# How to convert a date as a string to "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

We are using Moment.js to format the date.

How can I format such a date:

```
const createdAt = 'Mar 29 2019  5:02PM'
```

to a `dd/mm/yyyy` format?

I already tried with:

```
moment(createdAt).toDate();
moment(createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

but I got `Invalid date` for both.

Comment: What is the `get` function doing?

Comment: get is a lodash function, it's just to get the data `date` from the object `data`. 

I will change this 2 parameters, in an understandable way. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to specify the format because that is not a known date format, something like this:

```js
const result = moment('Mar 29 2019  5:02PM', "MMM DD YYYY  hh:mmA").format('DD/MM/YYYY');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is the correct solution and definitely works. Titus, I came up with D instead of DD, since based on the input I'd expect to see Mar 1 not Mar 01, but I don't think it would affect the outcome.

Comment: i Agree, thanks man. If you downvote my question because I didn't explain the get of lodash... well I deserve it. Not everybody knows it :) 

Really thank you for your solution, i will check as correct your answer asap.

Comment: Don't assume who downvoted you, or why, and don't take stackoverflow downvotes personally. People sometimes downvote what they think won't be a helpful question for others, not based on the quality or form of your question. Or because they've seen the question a bunch of times, or it's unclear, etc.

Comment: No i will never take it as personal...but if i see an error, well i have to be honest about it. I just tried to understand a better way to have a more clear answer, nothing more :) Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need `moment` to do that, especially if you need to tell it how to parse the string. For such a simply task, perhaps you could do it yourself?

```js
const convert = date_str =>
  date_str.toLowerCase().replace(/^(\w+) (\d+) (\d+) .+$/, (full_match, month, day, year) => {
    const month_num =
        month === 'jan' ? '01'
      : month === 'feb' ? '02'
      : month === 'mar' ? '03'
      : month === 'apr' ? '04'
      : month === 'may' ? '05'
      : month === 'jun' ? '06'
      : month === 'jul' ? '07'
      : month === 'aug' ? '08'
      : month === 'sep' ? '09'
      : month === 'oct' ? '10'
      : month === 'nov' ? '11'
                        : '12';
    return `${day}/${month_num}/${year}`
  });
  
console.log(convert('Mar 29 2019  5:02PM'));
```